# iMacros - How do i TAG a DIV with multiple Classes

Tags: tags, imacros

So i have this div that represents a button:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4">&nbsp;</div>
```

And i want to click on it using TAG. There is not an attribute that makes it easy to identify but the set of classes is unique. I am using this:

```
TAG TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:class1
```

but it doesn't seems to be working. I've tried to put all the classes enclosed by "" and '' and it breaks the buld.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to record this click? What is the result?

Comment: Yes, i've tried it, the result is something like:
`TAG POS=123 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:`
It's just a div with no text in it. the POS changes because the layout of the page is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up your element in inspector. Right click on it (in inspector I mean) and choose Copy Full Xpath

Then use the Xpath to refer your element in iMacros:

TAG XPATH="paste_full_Xpath_here"

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple classes as follows:

```
   TAG TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"class1 class2 class3"
```

Comment: I tried to add all the classes i found on this element but there was no luck.

Comment: Whats the actual HTML tag, If might be possible that your element is in different frame/iframe? Did you check for iframe?

Comment: It's a <div> tag, as i mentioned on the description.